# codeigniter how to make id visible in a method using foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am making a foreach loop inside the contrller but my code does not get the id.Here is the code:

```
    public function searches(){

     $search_data = $_POST['search_data'];
    $query = $this->news_model->get_live_items($search_data);

    foreach ($query as $row):
        echo "<li><a href='view/$row->id'>" . $row->title . "</a></li>";

    endforeach;
}
```

Comment: You are getting `title`?

Comment: Probably you are not getting data, because syntax seems to be okay.

Comment: @B.Desai I want to fetch items by id

Comment: Are you getting any output?

Comment: @JigarShah  haha. thanks buddy. my query was not selecting the id.I have just included that and its working like a charm.